# how to print out two arrays in php concatenating them

Tags: php, arrays, printing, echo

I have two arrays in my php that I want to print. I want them to be concatenated but I don't know how. The array for the $names prints but the description array "$desc" does not. is there any way to print both together?

```
    $query = "SELECT eName FROM Events";
            $query2 = "SELECT eDescription FROM Events";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            $names = array();
            $desc = array();
            echo "hello there people!" . $query . " ".$result;
            for($i=0; $i<sizeof($result); $i++){
                echo $result[$i] ."\n" . $result2[$i];
            }
            while($entry = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                $names[] = $entry[0];
            }
            while($entry2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)){
                $desc[] = $entry2[0];
            }
            echo "Which Event would you like to see?<br>";
            $stop = count($names);
            //echo $stop . "\n";
            $i = 0;
            print_r($names);                
            print_r($desc);
            foreach($names as $value){
                    echo $value . " " . $desc[i] ."<br>";   
                                     $i++;              
            }
```

Comment: Your loop index should be `$i`, not `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing two queries to get data from the same source?

```
$sql = mysql_query("select `eName`, `eDescription` from `Events`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo $row['eName']." ".$row['eDescription']."<br />";
}
```

Much simpler.

Comment: This is the most basic example of mysql usage, see [the documentation](http://php.net/mysql-query) examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        foreach($names as $key => $value){
                echo $value . " " . $desc[$key] ."<br />";                 
        }
```

As long as the array `$key` match, the information will be printed together.